# How to detect physical Ethernet cable connection on U-Boot?

Tags: connection, ethernet, u-boot

- Is there a provision to detect the Ethernet's physical cable connection from U-Boot?

We have seen some possible [methods on Linux (*userspace*)](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-detect-whether-a-physical-cable-is-connected-to-network-card-slot-on-linux) but couldn't find any references for U-Boot.

**The goal is to detect the physical connection and not just network state**

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

REF: NXP Community Post - https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/How-to-detect-Ethernet-cable-s-physical-connection-on-U-Boot/m-p/1466184

Comment: Your requirement is unclear and this seems to be an XY problem.  Is just one end of a patch cable plugged into the board's RJ45 socket the condition you want to detect?  Or does there have to be at least a link established (e.g. to a switch)?  Unless this is part of a diagnostic, such status information is IMO irrelevant, and the salient condition is a working connection to a server.

Answer (score 1):

The network phy drivers are in drivers/net/phy/. The read_status() method in struct phy_driver updates the field state in struct phy_device. This seems to be the value that you are looking for. Unfortunately this information is not easily accessible:

- not all network drivers use a phy_device
- the phy_device is not a sub-device of the network device in the driver model

It will require some architectural work to clean this up.